# Using an AMPscript loop to build a concat function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm wondering if it's possible to use an [AMPscript loop](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/ampscript_401/) to build a concat function from Data Extension rows.

Let's say I want to create a Base64 encoded string of pipe delimited data from rows in a Data Extension. Pretend for now that there are just 3 rows in that DE, then I could use the following code:

```js
%%[
var @rows, @row, @binaryStream

set @rows = LookupRows("My Data Extension","Campaign", "Welcome")

set @row1 = row(@rows,1)
set @row2 = row(@rows,2)
set @row3 = row(@rows,3)

set @binaryStream = Base64Encode(Concat(
  field(@row1,"id"),'|',field(@row1,"First Name"),'|',field(@row1,"Last Name"),Char(13),
  field(@row2,"id"),'|',field(@row2,"First Name"),'|',field(@row2,"Last Name"),Char(13),
  field(@row3,"id"),'|',field(@row3,"First Name"),'|',field(@row3,"Last Name")))
]%%
```

This would produce output, which when Base64 decoded would look like this:

```
1|Jack|Johns
2|Jane|Jones
3|Luke|Smith
```

That's fine. But what if I wanted to build the `@binaryStream` based on the number of rows in the DE using a FOR loop? For example, `for @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) do...` Can this be done in such a context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this...

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @binaryStream
set @rows = LookupRows("My Data Extension","Campaign", "Welcome")
SET @binaryStream = ""

FOR @i = 1 TO ROWCOUNT(@rows) DO
    SET @row = ROW(@rows,@i)    
    SET @binaryStream = CONCAT(@binaryStream,field(@row,"id"),'|',field(@row,"First Name"),'|',field(@row,"Last Name"))

    /* Add linefeed if this is not the last row */
    IF @i != ROWCOUNT(@rows) THEN
        SET @binaryStream = CONCAT(@binaryStream,Char(13))
    ENDIF
NEXT @i
SET @binaryStream = Base64Encode(@binaryStream)
]%%
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I tried something similar but was approaching it wrong. Interesting to see that you can set a variable on itself `SET @binaryStream = Base64Encode(@binaryStream)`, I've never tried that before!

Comment: Great answer @AndrewMcLeod! I have been looking for a way to add linefeeds, never thought to add via Char()! (boy is my face red)

Comment: @Gortonington Thanks, but I can't take any credit for putting unprintables into the output. The code was lifted from Eliot's original question.

Comment: @Gortonington, would you be able to join [the marketing-cloud chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58667/marketing-cloud) and participate in a related discussion of interest to you?